# OAuth Authentication with Cognito

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I have two applications both using Cognito for authentication. I want one application to be embedded inside of the other and to use OAuth2 or something to authenticate the user. I see lots of instructions for using Facebook, Google, and other social providers but nothing about using Cognito as the provider. If anyone has any suggestions where to start I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to keep your application code standards based and portable, so that you can switch between providers. I have some Cognito samples that may help you: https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/

Feel free to ask follow up questions - you are right that the docs are poor